# how to add a concat in an execute statement

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, execute

i have this statement that creates a table from a historic table, but i need to add the column llave which is concat from the next 2 columns and need to have the name "llave" , but i keep getting an error.

```
Declare @tablename AS nvarchar(80)

DECLARE @Str1 AS VARCHAR(100)='idticket'

DECLARE @Str2 AS VARCHAR(100)='-'

DECLARE @Str3 AS VARCHAR(100)= 'item'

Declare @temp AS nvarchar(80)

SET @tablename='reclamos_'+ 
    replace(replace(replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()), 112),'/','_'),':','_'),'.','_')`

set @temp = CONCAT(@Str1, @Str2, @Str3)

EXECUTE('Select' + @temp   +    ' , IdTicket TICKET, Item,  

idNegocio NEGOCIO, idTipoReclamo TIPO_RECLAMO, Entidad,  Periodo, Canal, Id_Order,
Id_Action_Order ID_ACTION, Id_Caso, Peticion_Requerimiento Peticion, Telefono, Producto, NombreBono NOMBRE_BONO,    NombrePenalidad NOMBRE_PENALIDAD,
OperacionComercial OPERACION_COMERCIAL,MontoCargoFijo MONTO_CARGO_FIJO, Fecha_Alta ,    MotivoReclamo MOTIVO_RECLAMO_GENERAL,   ExpReclamo DETALLE_RECLAMO, 
Respuesta,  CategoriaReclamo Categoria, DetalleReclamo Detalle, null    Entrada,    null Canal_2, null  Negocio_2,
null Producto_2, null   Casuistica, null det_analisis,  null det_analisis_2, null det_analisis_3, null tera_periodo,    idCanal,    RUC, null   id_producto 
      into '+ @tablename+ ' 
      ´from db_Robot_Reclamos.dbo.Reclamos
       where periodo = (
           select max(periodo) 
           from db_Robot_Reclamos.dbo.Reclamos)')
```

i try following another post which add the @str1,2 ,3 , i expect the concat work in the execute statement

Comment: What error?  If I copy your code I get syntax error on this:   @Syour texttr3  because that does not exist as a variable (though I think that is copy/past issue)  so what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Also I would build out a variable for your sql to execute then use Execute on the fully built SQL variable.  This way you can print the variable to see what the code looks like before executing.

Comment: It would help if you properly formatted your code, and fixed the major spelling/grammar errors. The way the question is posed makes it extremely difficult for a reasonable SO member to help you out

Comment: And btw, you need to use the `CONCAT` function

Comment: Show us the error. and what is this line `set @temp = CONCAT(@Str1, @Str2, @S`your text`tr3)`.

Comment: I've removed the "your text" as that is undoubtedly added by the SO code editor

Answer (score 0):

Add a space after select

```
EXECUTE('Select ' + @temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code `set @temp = CONCAT(@Str1, @Str2, @Str3)` will give you `Select idticket-item ....`.

But what I understand from your question that you want to concatenate the columns  `IdTicket` and `Item` to create a new column named `llave`.

If this what you want then:

replace

```
set @temp = CONCAT(@Str1, @Str2, @Str3)
```

with

```
set @temp = ' IdTicket + ''-'' + Item As llave'
```

You will get `Select IdTicket + '- ' + Item As llave .....` .

And I found character (`) before `FROM` statement, see if it is in your original text and remove it.

Full query.

```
Select IdTicket + '-' + Item As llave , IdTicket TICKET, Item,  idNegocio NEGOCIO, idTipoReclamo TIPO_RECLAMO, Entidad,  Periodo, Canal, Id_Order, Id_Action_Order ID_ACTION, Id_Caso, Peticion_Requerimiento Peticion, Telefono, Producto, NombreBono NOMBRE_BONO,    NombrePenalidad NOMBRE_PENALIDAD, OperacionComercial OPERACION_COMERCIAL,MontoCargoFijo MONTO_CARGO_FIJO, Fecha_Alta ,    MotivoReclamo MOTIVO_RECLAMO_GENERAL,   ExpReclamo DETALLE_RECLAMO,  Respuesta,  CategoriaReclamo Categoria, DetalleReclamo Detalle, null    Entrada,    null Canal_2, null  Negocio_2, null Producto_2, null   Casuistica, null det_analisis,  null det_analisis_2, null det_analisis_3, null tera_periodo,    idCanal,    RUC, null   id_producto into reclamos_202303 from db_Robot_Reclamos.dbo.Reclamos  where periodo = (select max(periodo) from db_Robot_Reclamos.dbo.Reclamos)
```